# The closure of the set of rational points in the Adeles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically integral projective variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then we may consider the closure $\overline{X(\mathbb{Q})}$ of $X(\mathbb{Q})$ inside the adelic points $X(\mathbb{A})=\prod_v X(\mathbb{Q}_v)$ of $X$. However, we may also take the closure $\overline{X(\mathbb{Q})}^v$ of $X(\mathbb{Q})$ inside $X(\mathbb{Q}_v)$ for any place $v$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.
Obviously we have $$\overline{X(\mathbb{Q})} \subset \prod_v \overline{X(\mathbb{Q})}^v \subset X(\mathbb{A}).$$

My question whether this first inequality is actually an equality?

My motivation is that I am trying to understand better $\overline{X(\mathbb{Q})}$ and what it looks like. I will simply note that the answer to my question is yes in the easy cases where $X$ satisfies weak approximation and when $X(\mathbb{Q})$ is empty.

Edit: To make sure there are not simple counter-examples like the one David pointed out below, I am assuming that $X(\mathbb{Q})$ is Zariski dense. I should also note that I am particularly interested in the case where $X$ is a fano variety.

Comment: If $X(\mathbb{Q})$ is finite of order $> 1$, as for an elliptic curve of rank 0 with nontrivial torsion, then $\overline{X(\mathbb{Q})}$ is finite, but $\prod_v \overline{X(\mathbb{Q})}^v = X(\mathbb{Q})^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountably infinite, isn't it?

Comment: @David: Yes of course thanks! I over looked this simple case as the case I have in mind $X$ is fano and $X(\mathbb{Q})$ is Zariski dense. I will edit my question.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the question: isn't true that, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is discrete in $\mathbb{A}$, the set $X(\mathbb{Q})$ is discrete (hence closed) in $X(\mathbb{A})$? (this is certainly the case for affine varieties).

Comment: @Daniel: WHAT???

Comment: First, $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$: a limit of integers is an integer. Second, when you endow $\mathbb{A}$ with its standard locally compact topology (if you consider another topology, you should mention it explicitly!), then $\mathbb{Q}$ is a discrete and co-compact subgroup: see A. Weil, Basic Number Theory, Theorem 2 in Chapter 4. Now let me try to make sense out of your previous comment. You insist in claiming that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{A}$, which makes me think that you are confusing between ad\`eles and finite ad\`eles. See more below. 

Comment: It is true that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the ring $\mathbb{A}_f$ of finite ad\`eles, but what is usually denoted $\mathbb{A}$ is $\mathbb{A}_f\times\mathbb{R}$. 

Comment: @Alain: the projective situation is completely different to the affine situation. $\mathbf{Z}$ is a long way from $\mathbf{Q}$, so $\mathbf{A}^1(\mathbf{Z})$ is a long way from $\mathbf{A}^1(\mathbf{Q})$, but $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q})=\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z)}$ by the valuative criterion for properness.

Comment: So to continue with your (Alain's) train of thought above, $\mathbb{Z}$ is closed and discrete in $\mathbf{R}$, but $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Z})$ is indeed dense in $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{R})$! Funny old world, eh?

Comment: @Daniel: It starts making sense. What is the simplest example of a projective variety for which you don't know the answer to the OP?

Comment: @Alain: projective 1-space satisfies weak approximation so both inclusions are equalities in this case. As David's comment above, and my answer below, show, the first inclusion is false for pretty much any other smooth projective curve the moment there is more than one rational point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example where $X(\mathbf{Q})$ is Zariski-dense but the first inequality is not an equality.

Let $X$ be an elliptic curve over the rationals, such that the group $X(\mathbf{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$. Let me first remind you what $X(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ looks like, for $p$ a prime where the curve has good reduction. There's a natural reduction map $X(\mathbf{Q}_p)\to\overline{X}(\mathbf{F}_p)$, with $\overline{X}$ the reduction of $X$, and this reduction map is surjective onto a finite target. Hence $X(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ naturally breaks up as a finite disjoint union of cosets of the kernel of this map, and the kernel is (and hence all the cosets are) clopen.

Now let $P$ be a generator of $X(\mathbf{Q})$, put the curve into minimal form, choose a random large prime $\ell$ and consider $Q:=\ell.P$. It will be easy to find an example where $Q=(x,y)$ and there are two primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ in the denominator of $x$ but not in the denominator of the coordinates of $P$, and such that $X$ has good reduction at these primes. In short it should be easy to find two primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that $P$ has order exactly $\ell$ modulo both $p_1$ and $p_2$.

But now the first inclusion must be strict, because even the closure of $X(\mathbf{Q})$ in $X(\mathbf{Q}_{p_1})\times X(\mathbf{Q}_{p_2})$ is easily seen to be strictly smaller than the product of the closures, for the "same reason" that if $P_1$ has order $\ell$ in the finite abelian group $G$ and $P_2$ has order $\ell$ in the finite abelian group $H$, then the group generated by $(P_1,P_2)$ in $G\times H$ is strictly smaller than the product of the subgroups generated by $P_1$ and $P_2$.

Comment: You must mean $l=14$, as $P=(0,0)$ is a generator of 37A, and $7P=(−{5\over 9},{8\over 27})$.


Comment: For example if $X$ is the rank 1 curve of conductor 37 and $P$ is a generator then one can take $\ell=17$ and $p_1=11$ and $p_2=139$.

Comment: [Junkie: you're right---thanks. I was using $2P$; I just deleted the comment and replaced it with a corrected one.]